# Objective-C--Parse NSString to a callable method

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

Could I parse an `NSString` to have it call a method that matches its name in Objective-C? Here is an example:

If I had a string called `doSomething`, and I had a method called `-(void) doSomething`, could I do something like `scanf` to parse whatever text I typed in to check if there were any method matching it, and if yes then call that method?

Comment: Being more specific would be great @Monolo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [NSSelectorFromString(@"methodName");](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSSelectorFromString) and the associated NSObject methods like [respondsToSelector:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/respondsToSelector%3a)

Answer (score 0):

jxpx777's answer will give you the information you were looking for, but in case you want more, the runtime has a long list of C functions that provide a fairly complete introspection of objects and classes.

For instance, if you want an `NSArray` of method names implemented by a class, you can do something like this:

```
Class myClass = [self class];

unsigned int methodCount;

Method *methods = class_copyMethodList(myClass, &methodCount);

NSMutableArray *methodNames = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];

for (int i = 0; i < methodCount; i++) {

    const char *methodNameCStr = sel_getName(method_getName(methods[i]));

    NSString *methName = [NSString stringWithCString:methodNameCStr 
                                            encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    [methodNames addObject:methName];
}

free(methods);

NSLog(@"Methods: %@", methodNames);
```

You will notice that plain C calls and Objective-C/Cocoa are mixed freely.